# Cannot open file created by previous app version in the user library

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsfilemanager

Oddly can't find much info regarding this error. I'm updating a very old iOS app which stored user files in the user library, in a subdirectory called "Private Documents".

I can list the files created fine, but I cannot read them, and receive the error "The file “1.xxx” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

```
let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
guard let documentDirectory = urls.first else {
    print("Cannot find old lib documents directory")
    return
}

guard let files = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Private Documents", isDirectory: true), includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions.skipsHiddenFiles) else {
    print("Cannot load old lib files directory")
    return
}
```

Files now contains an array of file URLs in this directory, correctly.

However, if I call FileManager.default.isReadableFile, this function always returns true, but then trying to copy the file into a Data(contentsOf: file) object fails with the above error.

Help appreciated!

Update: Checked app signing etc, comparing current App Store version to a TestFlight build I have the same issue.

Comment: try cleaning the project and clear the derived data. if it doesn't work, you can try changing the compiler to Default Compiler in the build settings.

Comment: Tried both of those, usually when seeing this error it's from people complaining their actual app doesn't run via Xcode because they've changed the executable or such :(

Answer (score 0):

Well well well... the issue was that the file I was reading were actually directories (packages). Hence all permissions, ownership, isReadable/isWritable were correct.

It's a shame the Apple error doesn't state that's the issue!